# Live temperature value update on website using sql, php, and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, sql

Honestly, I am extremely new to this world of programming, and I'm trying to learn as I go with my current project. I basically put this together off StackOverflow posts

Goal: I want to pull data from my MySQL database and display that data to the client and have it update on an interval without the need for refresh.

The code I currently have worked on local host, but when I ported it over to my web host it stopped working correctly. Currently, it will pull the data, and when it goes to do the refresh to update, it pulls data from the old PHP file unless you manually reload the PHP file as the client.

ctemp.php

```
include_once 'db_connect.php';


$sql = "SELECT * FROM weather WHERE id=1;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($resultCheck > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $ctemp = $row['temp'];
        print($ctemp);
    }
}
```

data.php

```
<?php>
    include_once 'api/db_connect.php';
    include 'header.php';
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
<body class="body1">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <header class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center py-3 mb-4 border-bottom">
            <h1 class="display-10 fw-bold">Sensor Data</h1>
        </header>
        <div class="p-5 mb-4 bg-light rounded-3">
                <div class="container-fluid py-5">

                    <div>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            function doRefresh(){
                                
                                $("#show").load("/api/ctemp.php");
                                
                                
                            }
                            setInterval(function(){doRefresh()}, 5000);
                        </script>
                       <h1 class="display-5"> 
                            The current temperature is: <b><span id="show"><?php include_once 'api/ctemp.php' ; ?></span></b><b><span>&#176;</span>C</b> or <b><span id="show2"><?php include 'api/ftemp.php' ; ?></span></b><b><span>&#176;</span>F</b>
                        </h1>

                    </div>
                    <br>
</body>
```

Comment: What if you go to `yourdomainhere.com/api/ctemp.php` directly? Does it show the temperature?

Comment: Actually, it's probably a caching issue. Having you tried adding cache control stuff to `ctemp.php`?

Comment: @RockySims Yes it shows the current data from my SQL table, and then the website will start showing that after you go to it directly. Then when it changes the refresh keeps bringing it back to that number.

Comment: So going to `yourdomainhere.com/api/ctemp.php` (where yourdomain.com is replaced with your actual domain), it shows the temperature and when you refresh that page it updates the temperature? Or does refreshing that page (`/api/ctemp.php`) keep showing the same temperature?

Comment: @RockySims Yes but the refresh function keeps reverting the website display to the number that I manually refreshed by going to /api/ctemp.php on each interval

Comment: I feel like maybe I'm not being clear. For now, pretend `data.php` does not exist and just type `yourdomainhere.com/api/ctemp.php` into the browser's url. Does refreshing that page result in updating the temperature displayed? Or does refreshing it just keep showing the same number every time?

Comment: @RockySims Sorry if I am confusing you. I got to yourdomainhere.com/api/ctemp.php, and it displays an old value. It takes one refresh on the page to get the current value from the SQL. So when my function doRefresh() is loading the yourdomainhere.com/api/ctemp.php on yourdomainhere.com/data.php, it is getting that old value. yourdomainhere.com/data.php updates to whatever value I last had manually opened on yourdomainhere.com/api/ctemp.php Hopefully, that makes a bit more sense.

Comment: Okay, I think I'm following now. That really sounds like a caching issue. Have you tried adding the 3 `header(...)` lines in `data.php` to `ctemp.php`?

Comment: @RockySims yes I did, and it didn't change anything.

Comment: Hmm. You said it was working on localhost but now that it's hosted, it doesn't work. Where is it hosted? Maybe I'll be able to get a better sense of what's happening if I can go to `/api/ctemp.php` myself and try it out.

Comment: @RockySims I am using Bluehost and my web address is bradypett.com. Just an FYI I'm an integrated engineering student and this is all just a side project I'm working on

Comment: Thanks. When I go to `https://bradypett.com/api/ctemp.php` it shows `300` and no matter how many times I refresh it still show `300`. Is that the same behavior you see? Actually it just changed to always showing `100`.

Comment: The key to debugging is splitting the problem space. To that end, try commenting out the code in `ctemp.php` and instead put `<?php echo rand() ?>` so that the number will be different every time (unless caching is truly the issue in which case it won't always appear to change). That should eliminate the possibility that the problem is something to do with mysql.

Comment: @RockySims So I did that, and now it shows a random number when I manually reload the page but when the refresh timer kicks in it keeps reverting to the same number. Should still be up if you want to see it.

Comment: Excellent. So I just took a look at `data.php` and look in the browser's Network tab (right click and choose Inspect then go to the Network tab). Notice that for the `ctemp.php` line it show `(disk cache)` under the Size column.

Comment: @RockySims any ideas how I would go about preventing this?

Comment: Don't have an answer yet but at least I'm reproducing the problem now. Let me see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Add `$.ajaxSetup({cache: false});` near the top of your javascript code (just above `function doRefresh(){` should be a good place to put it).